# Efficient way to convert a list to dictionary

Tags: python

I need help in the most efficient way to convert the following list into a dictionary:

```
l = ['A:1','B:2','C:3','D:4']
```

At present, I do the following:

```
mydict = {}
for e in l:
    k,v = e.split(':')
    mydict[k] = v
```

However, I believe there should be a more efficient way to achieve the same. Any idea ?

Comment: I believe there isn't anything more efficient than that. Remember that "fewer lines" is not the same as "faster". It all boils down to how the language expands those lines.

Comment: My comparison answer is updated, which compares related answers for short (4 items), long(13312 items) and very long (27262976 items) lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `dict()` with a generator expression:

```
>>> lis=['A:1','B:2','C:3','D:4']
>>> dict(x.split(":") for x in lis)
{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2', 'D': '4'}
```

Using dict-comprehension ( as suggested by @PaoloMoretti):

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in (e.split(':') for e in lis)}
{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2', 'D': '4'}
```

Timing results for 10**6 items:

```
>>> from so import *
>>> %timeit case1()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.09 s per loop
>>> %timeit case2()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.03 s per loop
>>> %timeit case3()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.17 s per loop
>>> %timeit case4()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.39 s per loop
>>> %timeit case5()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.82 s per loop
```

so.py:

```
a = ["{0}:{0}".format(i**2) for i in xrange(10**6)]

def case1():
    dc = {}
    for i in a:
        q, w = i.split(':')
        dc[q]=w

def case2():
    dict(x.split(":") for x in a)


def case3():
    {k:v for k,v in (e.split(':') for e in a)}

def case4():
    dict([x.split(":") for x in a])

def case5():
    {x.split(":")[0] : x.split(":")[1] for x in a}
```

Comment: @LtWorf `x.split(":") for x in lis` is a generator expression, not a list comprehension. Hence it doesn't allocate a temprary data structure

Comment: Yes my mistake, sorry. Anyway it's not more efficient. It's the same.

Comment: @LtWorf read this : http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops
LC's and generator expressions are faster than their equivalent `for` loop version.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Good suggestion , It didn't occur to me.

Comment: So we are saying that the generator expression is the most efficient;unless there is a need to allocate all memory at one shot(perhaps to avoid multiple client-server trips?),in which case the comprehension is preferred.Do I summarize this well?

Comment: @IUnknown LCs are somewhat faster than generator expression for small data, the difference is negligible though. But LCs require too much memory as they generate the whole list first, while genexp due to their lazy evaluation behaviour only yield one item at a time. So, unless you need to do save the intermediate data to do some work on it later then use LC, otherwise genexp are a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dict(map(lambda s: s.split(":"), ["A:1", "B:2", "C:3", "D:4"]))
{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2', 'D': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is better to compare them by execution time...

```
a = ['A:1','B:2','C:3','D:4']

def case1():
    dc = {}
    for i in a:
        q, w = i.split(':')
        dc[q]=w

def case2():
    dict(x.split(":") for x in a)


def case3():
    {x.split(":")[0] : x.split(":")[1] for x in a}


%timeit -n 100000 case1()
>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 1.95 us per loop


%timeit -n 100000 case2()
>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 us per loop


%timeit -n 100000 case3()
>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.39 us per loop
```

Tested for `100.000` loops and 3 test for each loop. ;As you can see, fastest execution time belong to `case1()`: standard `for loop`.

**Result:** 1 liner methods do not mean that they are faster, in fact, basic `for` loop is generally the fastest way to go.

**Update:** results for a list of 13312 items, basic list have 26 items, rest are the copies of those items wtihin the list. Timing is calculated over 1000 loops and best of 3 for each loop

```
%timeit -n 1000 case3()
1000 loops, best of 3: 9.49 ms per loop

%timeit -n 1000 case2() 
1000 loops, best of 3: 5.79 ms per loop

%timeit -n 1000 case1()
1000 loops, best of 3: 5.55 ms per loop
```

**Update 2:** Final test takes place with a list of `27262976` total items, basic list have 26 items, rest are the copies of those items wtihin the list. Timing is calculated over 10 loops and best of 3 for each loop (since execution of a very long list takes great time).

```
%timeit -n 10 case1()
10 loops, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop

%timeit -n 10 case2()
10 loops, best of 3: 12.1 s per loop

%timeit -n 10 case3()
10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 s per loop
```

Comment: But for nearly all applications I would still prefer case 2 as it’s just more obvious what you are doing.

Comment: Do you also have some results for a larger dataset?

Comment: @poke maybe, but question in here is _efficiency_, not readability.

Comment: Timing for just 4 items doesn't makes any sense, you can even use a `while` loop for such small number of items.

Comment: For 87 items, I get only an increase of 9% for the `dict()` solution vs. the manual for loop (I had about 89% for just 4 items).